# MinionPro is not displaying Cyrillic (and other) characters

Tags: typography, cyrillic, minionpro

I am following the directions in the `README` at the [CTAN entry for `MinionPro`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro). I am using the Minion Pro fonts from the [Adobe Font Folio 11](http://www.adobe.com/products/fontfolio/). I'm running a fully-updated TeX Live 2011 distribution on OS X Lion 10.7.2.

*Please note that I'm entirely aware this can be solved by using XeLaTeX (with `fontspec`), but I wish to use LaTeX in this case.*

Running `otfinfo -v` on any one of the 64 Minion Pro fonts yields,

```
Version 2.030;PS 2.000;hotconv 1.0.51;makeotf.lib2.0.18671
```

so naturally I'm using the `enc-2.000.zip` encoding files.

After unzipping `metrics-base.zip`, `metrics-full.zip`, `metrics-opticals.zip`, and `enc-2.000.zip` into my `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` directory, I ran `sudo mktexlsr`, then `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=MinionPro.map`, then `sudo mktexlsr` again.

I then typeset my test file, whose code and output is shown below.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[openg]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\section*{English}
Hello! How are you? This sentence has \textbf{bold}, \textit{italic}, and \textbf{\textit{bold italic}} characters. This sentence has \textsc{small caps}.

\section*{Russian}
Здравствуйте! Как у вас дела? Это предложение имеет \textbf{жирные}, \textit{курсивные}, и \textbf{\textit{жирные курсивные}} буквы. Это предложение имеет \textsc{капительные буквы}.

\section*{Equations}
\[
  \psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\rho) = \sqrt{\bigg(\frac{2}{na_0}\bigg)^3 \frac{(n - l - 1)!}{2n[(n + l)!]^3}} e^{-\rho / 2} \rho^{l} L_{n - l -1}^{2l + 1}(\rho) \cdot Y_{l}^{m}(\theta, \phi)
\]
\[
  y = x\tan(\theta) - \frac{g\sec^2(\theta)}{2v_0^2}x^2
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: image of test code output]

Note that the `openg` option also fails to display. This is strange to me, because it seems as if everything is working except for a few characters. Everything works great with XeLaTeX, but not when using the `MinionPro` package.

Forgive me if I'm being naïve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the current TeXLive version of `MinionPro` has no option [openg]. Without it I get the desired result.

[image]

With `lualatex` and

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
```

I get the same output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm aware this can be acheived using `fontspec`. I'm only perplexed as to why it won't work with `pdflatex`.

Comment: I used `pdflatex`, so it is a problem with your font setting.