# Missing glyphs of MinionPro font for cyrillic letters

Tags: pdftex, cyrillic, minionpro

I'm struggling with setting up `MinionPro` for cyrillic text on Windows8.1 (texlive2014, not Miktex).

I followed to this guide for [**FontPro installation**](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) at first
and then I did steps from these [instructions](http://carlo-hamalainen.net/blog/2007/12/11/installing-minion-pro-fonts) (using *Cygwin*).

As a result I could compile the following code based on the code from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41214/minionpro-is-not-displaying-cyrillic-and-other-characters) at least for english text:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}


\usepackage{MinionPro}
\makeatletter
 \def\Mn@Text@Family{MinionPro-TLF}
 \def\rmdefault{MinionPro-TLF}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section*{English}
Hello! How are you? This sentence has \textbf{bold}, \textit{italic}, and \textbf{\textit{bold italic}} characters. This sentence has \textsc{small caps}.

\section*{Russian}
Здравствуйте! Как у вас дела? Это предложение имеет 
\textbf{жирные}, \textit{курсивные}, и \textbf{\textit{жирные курсивные}} буквы. Это предложение имеет \textsc{капительные буквы}.

\section*{Equations}
\[
  \psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\rho) = \sqrt{\bigg(\frac{2}{na_0}\bigg)^3 \frac{(n - l - 1)!}{2n[(n + l)!]^3}} e^{-\rho / 2} \rho^{l} L_{n - l -1}^{2l + 1}(\rho) \cdot Y_{l}^{m}(\theta, \phi)
\]
\[
  y = x\tan(\theta) - \frac{g\sec^2(\theta)}{2v_0^2}x^2
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I need also cyrillic text and I got errors like that:

```
(file c:/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/adobe/minionpro/MinionPro-Bold.pfb): glyph `afii10093' undefined
(file c:/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/adobe/minionpro/MinionPro-BoldIt.pfb): glyph `afii10093' undefined
(file c:/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/adobe/minionpro/MinionPro-It.pfb): glyph `afii10085' undefined
(file c:/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/adobe/minionpro/MinionPro-Regular.pfb): glyph `afii10047' undefined
```

I've done the same steps for *Ubuntu* without any problems with cyrillic text. Any ideas how to overcome this? I'm using only `pdflatex` (for math purposes).

Comment: You should follow the instructions from [github](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro).  It should be sufficient to do `./scripts/makeall MinionPro` in cygwin bash.  Do not mix files from other resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After @ArashEsbati answer I realised that I should make a new attempt. 
The problem is unforeseen result of using of `Cygwin` and `texlive` on `Windows` (you may agree that `Windows` often has the lowest priority for maintainer's package tests).

I've successfully overcome my troubles in that way: after complete erasing `texlive2014` (with `.texlive2014` data) and installing fresh `texlive2015` I followed only FontPro installation guide steps as @ArashEsbati recommended.

I've typed next commands in `Cygwin bash`:

```
./scripts/install $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)  
mkdir -p --parents $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c
echo Map MinionPro.map >> $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c/updmap.cfg
mktexlsr $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)
updmap-sys
```

(from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251814/46415))

However, after all these steps for some unknown reasons `%MinionPro.map` section in file `c:/Users/$USER/.texlive2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` was empty causing errors like `font MinionPro-Regular-lf-l1-t1 at 382 not found`. You could verify if you have any records about `MinionPro` in your `pdftex.map` via command:

```
less `kpsewhich pdftex.map` | grep MinionPro*
```

To overcome the problem I just copied required lines from proper Linux-texlive `pdftex.map` to Windows-texlive `pdftex.map` and it began to work. I think it is reasonable to share `MinionPro.map` generated by Linux-updmap on FontPro font data (enc, tfm, pfb, etc.): [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/quw3225fopvx8b9/MinionPro.map?dl=0).

I have no idea why didn't MinionPro start work properly from the first time.
[image]

Comment: Is TEXMFLOCAL in your home directory? For TeX Live, it is recommended never to use `updmap`. I'm not sure about Cygwin. Maybe special considerations apply there. But unless you know that and how to adapt to them, probably this is the usual `updmap` problem. It looks as though you've previously done something to get files for updmap in maybe TEXMFHOME but have updated stuff for TEXMFLOCAL. Home trumps local and only one is read. Let me find you the reference.

Comment: Please read [my question/answer on this topic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i). Otherwise you are likely to continually encounter things which fail with fonts for 'unknown reasons'.

Comment: @cfr Very useful answer, now I'm understanding what happened. I confirm that I used `getnonfreefonts` in order to gain `garamondx`-font.
So now I need to reinstall the full TexLive-distribution and remake all the procedures again with knowledge about `updmap` and `updmap-sys`. Much obliged for your expanation!
By the way, `TEXMFLOCAL` is corresponding to  `C:/texlive/texmf-local`  variable (I checked it via command `kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL`).

Comment: You don't need to reinstall TL. There are instructions in my answer about 'what to do if you read this too late...'! In most cases, reinstalling TeX Live won't even help.

Comment: It's okay, I didn't do it. Too expensive and unreasoned action. Thank you for mentioning that section directly, it's what I need.